# Storing integer pairs in a matrix in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix of integer pairs in Python, where the 'x-axis' are numbers 0 - 30 in increments of 5, and y-axis is 20 - 40 in increments of 5. So something like:

```
Row 1: [20,0] [20,5] ... [20,30]
Row 2: [15,0] [15,5] ... [15,30]
```

etc.

1. How would I generate such a matrix in Python?
2. How would I read individual integers out of each tuple in the matrix?

In Matlab it's quite simple, but I'm just starting out in Python. I do not need to modify the elements in the matrix, but will be reading them out.

Comment: Do you want _tuples_ or _lists_? They're entirely different!

Comment: I might be using the wrong terminology - I should say I want a matrix of integer pairs (edited main post).

Comment: does the code in my answer suit your needs?

Comment: Yes, perfect thanks! How would I reference a specific integer from one of the pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=[]

xmax=30
ymax=40
step=5; t=0

for x in xrange(0,xmax+1,step):
    a.append([])
    for y in xrange(20,ymax+1,step):
        a[t].append((x,y))
    print "Row {}: {}".format(t+1,a[t])
    t+=1
```

Output:

> Row 1: [(0, 20), (0, 25), (0, 30), (0, 35), (0, 40)]
>
> Row 2: [(5, 20), (5, 25), (5, 30), (5, 35), (5, 40)]
>
> Row 3: [(10, 20), (10, 25), (10, 30), (10, 35), (10, 40)]
>
> Row 4: [(15, 20), (15, 25), (15, 30), (15, 35), (15, 40)]
>
> Row 5: [(20, 20), (20, 25), (20, 30), (20, 35), (20, 40)]
>
> Row 6: [(25, 20), (25, 25), (25, 30), (25, 35), (25, 40)]
>
> Row 7: [(30, 20), (30, 25), (30, 30), (30, 35), (30, 40)]

---

Speaking about extracting numbers from this list, you can do it as follows:

- let the list be named as `a`
- if you want to extract a number from the first row, use `a[0]` (list indices always start with 0!)
- if you want to get the first tuple, use `a[0][0]` (in this example it will give you `(0, 20)`
- `x` is `a[0][0][0]` and `y` is `a[0][0][1]`